# Sending image from AWS Lambda function gets corrupted

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an image in an s3 bucket that I'm trying to pass along in a response. I managed to do so but the file gets corrupted on the way.

Lambda code:

```
def get_file(file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket = 'my_bucket'
    file = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)['Body'].read()
    encoded_bytes = base64.b64encode(file)
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
    }
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'IsBase64Encoded': True,
        'body': json.dumps({'file': base64.b85encode(encoded_bytes).decode('utf-8')}),
        'headers': headers
    }
    return response
```

Converting it to bytes again and attempt to save it as an image:

```
img = str.encode(string)
with open('image.jpeg','wb') as f:
    f.write(img)
```

Am I doing something wrong when sending it from AWS?

Thanks!

Comment: why you don't generate a singed url instead? and send the url in the response, and let the client get the image directly from s3

Comment: Why are you using b85encoding?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading the image in Lambda and sending it in the response, you better use s3 signed URL, it allows you to generate a temporarily signed URL, then you can send this URL to the client and let it download the image directly from s3.

Comment: But to do so I would need to have the bucket open for public access, right? It feels safer to keep it closed and the only way to get data is from the lambda

Comment: No, the bucket will still be private, you only send a signed url to the authenticated client, the signed url is an open url only for one object.

Comment: An [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) provides temporary access to a private object stored in an S3 bucket. You can generate it with a few lines of code using credentials that have permission to access the object. This way, the application has full control of _who_ can access _which_ object.

Comment: Thanks John, I'll take a look at doing so. Would that be a good solution in a dropbox-like app? How long lived are the urls valid?